# Why does R plot the wrong distribution in this case?

Tags: r, statistics, normal-distribution

I'm relatively new to R and I've been trying to simulate a normal distribution with R's builtin functions rnorm and dnorm and subsequently plotting it.

Why is it the case that it plots this wrong density function when my code is this

```
x <- rnorm(1000, mean=5, sd=2)
hist(x, border='red',freq=F)
y <- curve(dnorm(x,mean(x), sd(x)), add=T)
```

[image]

but when my code is like this it does plot the correct density function

```
x <- rnorm(1000, mean=5, sd=2)
hist(x, border='red',freq=F)
meanx <- mean(x)
sdx <- sd(x)
y <- curve(dnorm(x,meanx,sdx), add=T)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`curve()` does not take a vector of values as the first expression.  It takes an *expression*.  When you write `dnorm(x)` while `x` is an object in your global environment, you are creating a vector of values, not an expression.

This is confusing and you got unlucky because `x` happens to be the name of the first argument of `dnorm()`, which is why your code runs without error, but doesn't produce the expected output.

Sorting this out becomes more clear if you re-name your object `x` to be `xx`.

Then your original code throws an error because `dnorm(xx)` is not an expression:

```
set.seed(1234)
xx <- rnorm(1000, mean=5, sd=2)
hist(xx, border='red',freq=F)
curve(dnorm(xx ,mean(xx), sd(xx)), add=T)

Error in curve(dnorm(xx, mean(xx), sd(xx)), add = T) : 
  'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'
```

But using the `dnorm()` argument name `x` along with your data `xx` to create an expression (`dnorm(x, mean(xx), sd(xx))`) works as expected:

```
set.seed(1234)
xx <- rnorm(1000, mean=5, sd=2)
hist(xx, border='red',freq=F)
curve(dnorm(x, mean(xx), sd(xx)), add=T)
```